# CircleCI Postgres connection fails in build but not when SSH'd in

Tags: node.js, postgresql, circleci, node-postgres

I'm using CircleCI to run tests / builds for a node.js project (node 8.9). I have to use the machine executor, as I need ipv6 support, and I also run my tests using postgres. The local postgres instance is run using docker (`docker run -d -p \"5432:5432\" postgres:9.6`). I'm using `pg@7.4.1` to connect to postgres.

I have a script which sets up the test databases (users, db, etc.) which is run in a subsequent step, after the postgres container has come up. When this script is run in the build, I get the following error:

```
Connecting to PG
Error occurred Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
    at Connection.con.once (/home/circleci/converge-ingest/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:179:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/circleci/converge-ingest/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:122:10)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Exited with code 1
```

If I then try to rebuild via SSH and run the script manually it works fine. I have dumped and compared the environments between the build and the SSH session and the differences are minor and completely unrelated, thus could not have had any impact. I have also tried forcing my script to wait for 2s just in case the postgres instance hasn't finished starting up. None of this helps.

I'm not sure what else to do to be able to debug this problem, as it works when I run the script in the VM on CircleCI.

Is there something I'm missing which would cause these do things to behave so differently?

Comment: This would be a good question to ask in CircleCI Discuss. My first thought, the script is trying too connect before Postgres/Docker can get fully initialized. I'd try adding some delay, or wait for the port to be open and ready.

Comment: @FelicianoTech as I noted in my question, I've tried adding a delay. It turns out this wasn't the problem - I've detailed the solution in my answer (although it is still a bit strange).

Comment: Ah, that wasn't obvious to me. Thanks for coming back with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was to do with the shell configuration *for this script*. It's still a bit strange, but I had to change the shell to a login shell:

```
  - run:
      name: "Setup clean test db"
      command: "node ./scripts/clean_test_db.js"
      shell: /bin/bash --login
```

This makes it behave in the same way as my shell did during the SSH session. What I am unclear about it why this is true for this script (which runs using `node`) but not for others which run using `npm run X`.

Either way, this solves the problem completely.